# javascript how to insert new elements at different locations in page

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-chrome-extension, insert

I'm writing a chrome extension that will add helper text instructions/reminders to specific location in the "new order" form we use at work. I'm really new to coding (basically using this project as a way to learn). I've created something that works - but I'm convinced there's a more elegant solution that I just haven't been able to figure out.

```
var helpText = "this is the message"
var customAlert = makeAlert(helpText)   //create html container for msg

function makerAlert(helpText){...}   //createElem, add class/style, append children
```

I'm okay with that bit (above). But should i be storing information on each message in objects instead? why would/wouldn't i? what information would go in it?

```
function alertPlacer(customAlert){
    var par = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[i];
    var sib = par.childNodes[j];
    par.insertBefore(customAlert, sib);
};
```

really struggling with this bit (above). I have actually made alertPlacer() functions for each message because i can't figure out how to create a function that will take different class name & index parameters. should i be breaking this up more? if i stored these bits of info in an object, would that be useful?

***relevant info:***

- because the target locations are *within* a form, almost nothing has an "id" attribute. so i have to use getElementsByClassName & an index.
- for each message, I know the target parent className & index and the child node index to "insert before".
- i would like to stick with javascript-only solution.

Comment: Well first, why would you ever need that variable? If you need the information just call the elements again and grab the information. AS far as why you wouldn't, random extra unneeded variable to manage

Answer (score 0):

functions can take multiple arguments:

```
function alertPlacer(customAlert,className,parIndex,childIndex){ 
    var par = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[parIndex]; var sib = par.childNodes[childIndex];      
    par.insertBefore(customAlert, sib); 
};
```

And you call your function like

```
alertPlacer(yourAlert,"class-name",6,9);
```

Comment: Oh wonderful, thank you! I knew that functions could take multiple arguments but I couldn’t seem to make it work - I think I was just doing it wrong. This works great!.

If I were to store those arguments as property values of an object, how would I call the function?